# Show img from img slider in modal on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image-slider and I want the user to be able to click on the currently displayed img and then see it in a modal. The difficulty is that the images are layered on top of one another. Hence, with my current approach of putting whatever img was clicked in the modal, the topmost img is the only one that can ever be shown in the modal.

Is there a way to display (in the modal) whichever image is currently being displayed in the slider when the user clicks the slider? You can see my current progress at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/t8Lyarmc/1/). Here's the jquery that I'm currently using to show the clicked on img in a modal:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
            $('img').on('click', function() {
                var sr = $(this).attr('src');
                $('#mimg').attr('src', sr);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: the image slider you are using, is it created with CSS only? no JS?

Comment: It changes the 'slide' container of any non-viewed images to opacity 0. So what I'm trying at the moment is to change `var sr = $(this).attr('src');` to get the img inside the closest 'slide' div with opacity 1... Easier said than done!

Comment: then you can simply trigger modal with `data-attributes` adding in `img` and use event listener to show the relative image in modal and no need of click event

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow (and I bet that's on me!).

Comment: Here's a somewhat cleaned up [newer version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/t8Lyarmc/3/) that shows what I'm trying with the jquery.

Comment: the problem is `opacity` it makes the image invisible but the image is still there, use `visibility` and then off-course you may need to adjust other CSS properties too but it will fix the issue

Comment: here is your original fiddle, with modal event and `visibility` property http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lyarmc/4/

Comment: added `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` into `img` to trigger modal and used event `show` to show the relative image in modal when clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lyarmc/5/, with `visibility` property

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks. Is there any chance I'll be able to keep the fadeout effect if I go this route?

Comment: and if you want to use `opacity` then use `z-index` too with it http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lyarmc/9/  here is an example with `opacity` property, if `opacity:0` then `z-index:0` and if `opacity:1` then `z-index:1` it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/t8Lyarmc/10/)

It looks like you're not selecting the current slide's image. I found the current slide by looping through the slides and checking their opacity.

### Remove this

```
var sr = $(this).attr('src');
```

### Replace with this

```
var sr;
$(this).closest('.slides').find('.slide-container').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).find('.slide').css("opacity") === 1) {
        sr = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one remaining question. Is it possible to do this in such a way that it only checks the slides nearest to the click event? I ask because I'm using several of these sliders on a page. I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the code now.

Comment: I updated it so the code searches for `.slide` closest to the click event.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!